# Interface VLAN IP address not on exclude list?

Tags: cisco, vlan, dhcp

Does an IP address need to be included in a `ip dhcp excluded-address x.x.x.x` if its already included in an interface vlan?

Examples:

`ip dhcp excluded-address 10.3.8.1 10.3.8.20`

```
interface Vlan30
 description Voice
 ip address 10.3.8.1 255.255.248.0
 no ip redirects
```

Comment: It wont let me award the bonus until after 24 hours. I still have 5-6 hours to go before im able to award it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not required.

cisco says,

> The IP address configured on the router interface is automatically
>   excluded from the DHCP address pool.

More details are [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4/dhcp-12-4-book/config-dhcp-server.html#GUID-9DFE5A79-4529-4DD9-BB7B-CB46C10E9ABE) (cisco official site)

Answer (score 3):

No, the router is smart enough to not hand out is own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include in excluded address . Instead of this include  mentioned command in DHCP pool . This command will avoid allocating this ip address to hosts

`Router(config) #IP dhcp default gateway   10.3.8.1`